# Going to Bulgaria with single entry Schengen visa

Tags: visas, schengen, schengen-visas, spain, bulgaria

I already found some post about this question but they are a bit old dated.

I’m holder of Schengen visa with single entry issued by Spain.

I’m planning to go from Sofia to Barcelona because it’s way cheaper than Istanbul( the place I’m from )

So my question, is it possible to enter Bulgaria to attend a flight for Sofia to Barcelona with my single entry Schengen visa?

Thanks…

Comment: The 2014 decision mentioned in https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/74609/single-entry-schengen-visa-for-bulgaria is still in force and the [Bulgarian Ministy of foreign affairs](https://www.mfa.bg/en/services-travel/consular-services/travel-bulgaria/visa-bulgaria) still confusingly refers to an earlier decision. So I do not see any change that would make that Q&A “dated”. Obviously, the answer wasn't entirely satisfying and that hasn't changed either.

Comment: So you say that single entry Schengen visa is not allowed to entry Bulgaria?

Comment: I am not saying that, I find the information available very confusing and I haven't tried it myself. What I am saying is that what I wrote in 2016 remains true and in particular the 2014 EU decision is still in force. It also means that whatever you may read elsewhere about a similar trip in the last 6-7 years should also be true (anything older than 2014 on the other hand would not necessarily apply today).

Comment: Personally I wouldn't try it but if you do and you are successful, feel free to tell me if I was wrong or answer the other question too!

Comment: I will call the embassy tomorrow lets see

Comment: No one ones anything about this question unfortunately

Comment: Yes I know :( One thing that may have changed is the attitude of Bulgarian border guards. They are not known to be the most rigorous and, anecdotally, I have friends who told me they can be hostile against Turkish citizens / cars with Turkish plates but that was getting better, especially compared to Serbia.

Comment: Problem is that will they allow me to attend flight :) I’m not that concerned about getting into Bulgaria border

Comment: Oh, if you make it to Sofia, I would not be too concerned, you have a valid visa for your destination, they cannot cancel it themselves. They could theoretically try to fine you and ban you from Bulgaria or something like that but they have no reason to try to keep you there and it would mean overruling their colleague who let you into the country. I think the main concern here is being turned back when entering Bulgaria.

Comment: You would travelling by road, right?

Comment: Yes by bus from Istanbul to Sofia

Comment: Like I said my main concern is to make it from airport to Barcelona

Comment: I don't think you need to be concerned about that, the main obstacle will be entering the country. It's very easy for border guards to force you off the bus and turn you back.

Comment: @Relaxed But if Bulgaria sees the OP's visa as single-entry, which has already been "used" for the OP's entry into Bulgaria, isn't the a risk not the Bulgaria entry, but instead that the OP will be denied boarding in Sofia for the Barcelona-bound flight?

Comment: @DavidSupportsMonica Bulgaria is not a Schengen area

Comment: Yes, I know that. But Bulgaria allows use of a Schengen visa for entry into Bulgaria. If the Schengen visa is single-entry, it's possible that an over-zealous airline check-in clerk in Sofia might see that the visa has already been used, and refuse check-in for a flight to the Schengen area. Multiple-use (in Bulgaria and the EU) of a single-use Schengen visa is the issue discussed here.

Comment: @DavidSupportsMonica "Use" may be a bit imprecise here, what's happening is that Bulgaria exempts Schengen visa holders from any visa requirement for short visits. But single entry still means one entry *in the Schengen area* and could hardly mean anything else. Other countries also unilaterally grant transit or visit privileges to Schengen visa holders, including non-EU Balkan countries and Turkey. Schengen Border guards cannot possibly monitor these rules or let other countries impact the validity of a Schengen visa. So the visa is still undoubtedly valid in my view.

Comment: At the same time, Bulgaria may seem like a bit of a special case as it is in fact an EU country and these rules were intended as a stop-gap measure before fully joining the Schengen area. Furthermore, in the logic of the Schengen acquis, single-entry visa holders are generally less trusted than multiple visa holders. That may be why EU decision 565/2014/EU only foresees an exemption for *multiple or two-entry* visa holders and that's why I am most concerned about entry in Bulgaria.

Comment: On the other hand, it would be absurd to admit someone that may not be able to continue on their journey, make their visa invalid, and force them to stay in the country longer than they wish. If Bulgaria has any concern about the legality of this journey, the logical place to enforce the rules is at the entry point, when getting rid of any unwanted visitor is cheap and easy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only enter Bulgaria with a multiple entry Schengen visa.  If you try to do this with a single entry schengen visa you will almost certainly not be allowed to enter.  If you fly into Bulgaria via Sofia airport, you may be able to transit without a visa if you stay in the international area and have a connecting flight out within 24 hours.  I know that is not exactly what you asked but it is a potential solution.

However when you applied for the Schengen visa you would have provided your planned travel itinerary and the application would have been considered and visa issued to accommodate this schedule.